# Is brass combustible in high pressure oxygen environment?

Tags: metal, combustion, pressure

Some metals are particularly ignitable in high pressure oxygen environments, like stainless steel and aluminum. Copper and nickel, on the other hand will self-extinguish when ignited. Does anyone know about brass?

Comment: Don't know what you consider high pressure, but oxygen regulators for 2000 psi tanks are made of brass.

Comment: And the tanks themselves are carbon steel.

Comment: Metals do not ignite in ambient temperature oxygen , with the possible except exception of alkali metals like lithium. If the question refers to high temperatures, what high temperatures ?